# Force the server to define $_SERVER['HTTP']

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I need to copy a website from a server to another. In the first server, `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is defined but, in the second, I have this error`Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS`. **I don't want to change the code**. I have to do multiple copies and modify the code as less as possible.

How to force the server to set a value at `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`?

Comment: `I don't want to change the code`. You could add one line to your bootstrap file. That's all you need to do.

Comment: turn on https? but don't hack up the server to compensate for bad code.

Comment: @JohnConde On all of the websites I will copy? I don't think it's the cleanest solution. Why a down vote?

Comment: @MarcB, this is not a bad code. There may be difference of configuration between the two servers. I want to have a config as similar as possible.

Comment: Do you have mod_ssl enabled on the server where HTTPS environmental variable is not defined? This environmental variable will only be available if this module is enabled.

Comment: code that assumes $_SERVER['https'] is always present without putting in an `isset()` check is bad. maybe not horribly catastrophically bad, but still bad.

Comment: I would agree with @MarcB here. At a minimum you should change your code to assume HTTPS is off is the HTTPS Apache environmental variable is not available in `$_SERVER`

Comment: @MarcB, bad or not is not the question. I want to do a clear copy of a site. I will correct bugs after I replicated the site correctly but do two thinks at the same time is a bad practice.

Comment: then turn off the warnings, which is equally bad - the equivalent of sticking your fingers in your ears and going "lalalala can't hear you".

Comment: @MarcB, I'm transferring a website, not correcting it. It's not the moment to check all the code to see if it respect the good practices. Furthermore, this difference is maybe a sign of other differences and I want to have the same configuration on both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Apache, and assuming that you have `.htaccess` enabled you can add (or modify) this with:

```
SetEnv HTTPS yourvaluehere
```

This should define `HTTPS` in your `$_SERVER` superglobal.

If you don't want to edit `.htaccess` then you could set up or modify a VHost entry and `SetEnv` there.

Not sure how effective this will be for your codebase. YMMV.

Comment: Just to add: obviously I am just suggesting this as an aid for getting your codebase running in a dev environment, which I assume is your use case. I think that you should definitely consider suggestions Marc B etc. made in the comments recommending that the codebase be modified to allow portability and ease environmental pain.

Comment: You might have to test this. There are a number of things that could be happening. Some questions: Do you have an existing .htaccess file? If not, I assume you just created one and added this value. Then you need to check if Apache is configured to read .htaccess files. The easiest way to do this is to save some random trash text and see if this triggers an "Internal Server Error" message or similar. Let me know how you get on with this, and I will try to advise further.

Comment: In addition to this, the most surefire way to test if this has worked is to create a `test.php` file in your webroot, and add something like `<?php echo isset($_SERVER['https']) ? $_SERVER['https'] : 'not working';`